# How to access javascript function cordova from swift?

Tags: swift, cordova, cordova-plugins

I know that we can access swift function from cordova using plugin (exec).

Is there possible for swift function to call cordova javascript function ?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this it is entirely possible to call a JavaScript function from Swift, all you need is a reference to the cordova web view.

IIRC, older versions of Cordova use the `UIWebView` while more recent versions use the newer `WKWebView`. Executing JavaScript functions differs slightly depending on which web view you're using.

### WKWebView

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame)
view.addSubview(webView)
let greeting = "Your age is: "
let age = 50

// Notice the single-quotes needed to pass greeting as a string.
let javaScript = "function doSomething(a, b) { return a + b };doSomething('\(greeting)', \(age))"
webView.evaluateJavaScript(javaScript, completionHandler: { object, error in
    print(object)  // Prints Your age is: 50
})
```

Note that the `WKWebView` must be visible (added as a subview to a visible view) for it to execute JavaScript.

### UIWebView

Execute arbitrary JavaScript functions using `UIWebView`'s `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:)`. For example:

```
let uiWebView = UIWebView()
let greeting = "Your age is: "
let age = 50

// Notice the single-quotes needed to pass greeting as a string.
let javaScript = "function doSomething(a, b) { return a + b };doSomething('\(greeting)', \(age))"
let result = uiWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(javaScript)
print(result) // Prints Your age is: 50
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CDVPlugin` type has a member called `commandDelegate` which is of the type `CDVCommandDelegate`. On there you find the function `evalJs`.

```
@objc(MyPlugin) public class MyPlugin : CDVPlugin {
  override public func pluginInitialize() {
    commandDelegate.evalJs("console.log('hello js')")
  }
}
```